# Grails exclude EmailValidator (commons-validator) dependency

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-2.0

I'm trying to exclude the Apache Commons library version 1.4.0 from Grails default dependencies as it has a bug;
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9000

Some have suggested overriding with a new dependency and so I've tried the following to no avail.

```
inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
        excludes 'commons-validator'
    }

...

dependencies {
    compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.1"
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to property achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute `grails dependency-report` on a fresh Grails 2.5.5 application you can see:

```
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.5.5
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.5.5
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
```

I think it should work if you only add the dependency and remove the `excludes`. Now if we execute the dependency report:

```
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.5.5
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.5.5
+--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.1
```

The version `1.4.0` is not in the classpath anymore.